# chessboardjs how to set black to move first?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the chessboardjs JavaScript library.
I load the position with the following code:

```
var board = new ChessBoard('board');
board.start(false);
var currentPosition = FENSTRING; //'r1bqkbnr/pppp1ppp/2n5/1B2p3/4P3/5N2/PPPP1PPP/RNBQK2R';
board.position(currentPosition, false);
```

Now I want black to move first.
How can I do this ? I read all the documentation on http://www.chessboardjs.com and can not find a way to tell the board so black must move first.

Answer (score 2):

chessboardjs is "[just a board](https://github.com/oakmac/chessboardjs/#what-is-chessboardjs)" and has no knowledge of the game of chess. ie: who's turn it is, what moves are legal, etc

(disclaimer: I am the author of chessboardjs)

Comment: Hi where i can find the complete documentation of chessboard.js? example move function so as to cater to en passant and promotion i have my own custom parser so just need a API documentation.

Answer (score 0):

That's against the very rule of the game, Chess. Only white makes the first move, and that is how it should be, because that's how it is designed to be.

Black never makes the first move.

You could however alter the images of the pieces as it is how they're managed in the link you've given, and try to *make it look* like Black is making the first move.

Comment: The FENSTRING variable loads a specific position.  Once the position has been loaded it is no longer white that must move first .  Black needs to move then at that specific position.